# Как вставить переменную в Query Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-jpa

У меня есть такой `Query`:

```
    @Modifying
    @Query( value = " select * " +
        " from tabela_testowa t1 " +
        " where not exists ( " +
        "        select id " +
        "        from tabela_testowa t2 " +
        "        where t2.id <> t1.id and ( " +
        "                    t2.kolumna1 = t1.kolumna2 or " +
        "                    t2.kolumna3= t1.kolumna2 " +
        "            ) " +
        "    ) ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Test> getAllUniqColumn(@Param("mainColumn") String mainColumn,
                                @Param("secondColumn") String secondColumn,
                                @Param("thirdColumn") String thirdColumn);
```

Я хочу заменить на:

```
    @Modifying
    @Query( value = " select * " +
        " from tabela_testowa t1 " +
        " where not exists ( " +
        "        select id " +
        "        from tabela_testowa t2 " +
        "        where t2.id <> t1.id and ( " +
        "                    :secondColumn = :mainColumn or " +
        "                    :thirdColumn = :mainColumn " +
        "            ) " +
        "    ) ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Test> getAllUniqColumn(@Param("mainColumn") String mainColumn,
                                @Param("secondColumn") String secondColumn,
                                @Param("thirdColumn") String thirdColumn);
```

Но к сожалению второй вариант кода не работает правильно. Вместо того чтобы фильтровать данные он возвраает все даные из таблицы. Как заменить `sql` код на переменную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае вы не можете подставлять названия колонок через параметры в запросы. Только конкретные значения (строки в кавычках, числа и т.п.).

Скорее всего вам придется "склеить" запрос руками. Можно сделать это:

- на стороне СУБД: сделайте хранимую процедуру, которая принимает названия столбцов, склеивает запрос, вызовите ее через `@Query("call my_proc(:mainColumn, :secondColumn: :thirdColumn))`;
- на стороне java: откажитесь от JPA для данного запроса и обработайте его через JDBC или `JDBCTemplate` спринга.